# Debug RESTful service from external device, unfamiliar error message

Tags: rest, debugging, visual-studio-2015, netsh

I have been working on a RESTful service (with VS 2015) for about 4 months now, on a Windows 7 development laptop (I don't know if Windows 7 is playing a role here, but I mention it for completeness).

I just purchased a new development machine with Windows 10.  I copied my code to that machine, installed VS2015, etc (re-created my development environment).

When I right-click the service project and select Debug->Start new instance, everything works fine, and I can interact with the service from a browser using "http://localhost:[port]/api....."

However, I wish to interact with the service via my android app, that I am developing.  I followed the instructions here:

http://becdetat.com/access-iis-express-from-another-machine.html

Namely, I ran the "netsh" command, made the necessary changes to applicationhost.config, etc.  On my Windows 7 machine, this worked great and I was able to develop my mobile app.

However, on my new machine, the command:

netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.xx.xx:[port]/ user=everyone

causes me to get an error when I attempt to start the service in the debugger.  The error is "There was a temporary DNS error.  Try refreshing the page.  Error Code:  INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND"

If I then execute:

netsh http delete urlacl url=http://192.168.xx.xx:[port]/

the service runs fine, but I still cannot access it from my android device.

As I mentioned, this worked just fine on my Windows 7 machine.

Thanks for any help.....

Comment: I stumbled upon a solution that worked for me, though I'm at a loss as to why...I found this article:  https://www.ryadel.com/en/iis-express-allow-external-requests-remote-clients-devices/     -- in it, they suggest running the netsh command like this:  "netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:<port>/ user=everyone", instead of specifying an IP address like the other article I mentioned.  This worked for me

Comment: Hi Jeff, it seems that your issue is resolved, you can consider turn this comment into an answer to help others. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Just a reminder:)